# Is "How far did Dan come in his Early access play of Subnautica?" grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, questions, deictic-verbs

Someone asked this question on a stream I was watching and was told it's not grammatically correct.

> How far did Dan come in his early access play of Subnautica?

If it's incorrect, what would be the right way to ask that?

"early access" is like a Beta version
"Subnautica" is a video game
"Dan" is the streamer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How far did Dan come in his early access play of Subnautica?

There are two issues with this sentence. First and simplest, the idiomatic term for progress would be **get**.

The second issue is the context of the word [play](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/play). When talking about games, play is the activity of playing rather than the game that is being played. The compound adjective **early access** could be applied to a game or to a version of a game, but it cannot be applied to an activity.

A better way to write this sentence would therefore be

> How far did Dan get in his early access version of Subnautica?

Comment: People in the streaming community do use the word "playthrough" however. so "How far did Dan get in his early access **playthrough** of Subnautica?" would be fine.

Comment: While I agree "early access version" or "early access playthrough" are better, the gaming community isn't known for its strict adherence to grammar rules.  "Early access play" makes perfect sense in context.

Comment: @Andrew, agreed: maybe that's why the OP asked this question here rather than asking fellow gamers?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is fine except for the use of "come".  The idiomatic question when asking degree of success in reaching some goal is:

> How far did you **get**?

So in this case:

> How far did Dan **get** in his early access play of Subnautica?

I have to disagree with Sean's answer.  "Go" is not natural for this context.